# Make button show Toast message only once for subsequent presses

Tags: android

I am very new to android and this is my first day doing it. I am creating this app which has 2 buttons and is responsible for changing the color of the layout once it is pressed. As the button is pressed, I am using Toast class to display a message saying that the color is changed. **But I want the logic to be such that the toast message for a particular button is displayed only once and not for subsequent same button presses.** To do this I used a boolean flag and as soon as the button is clicked, changed the boolean variable to false and then not display the toast message. But there is a problem in this logic. The app will not display the toast message for future clicks. I would really appreciate if anyone would help me a little bit in this logic so that the app would know be smart enough to handle future presses.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button myblue_button;
    private Button mygreen_button;
    private LinearLayout backGround;
    private TextView textArea;
    boolean forBLue = true;
    boolean forGreen = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textID); //id for text area to later change it
    backGround = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutID);
    myblue_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue_button);
    myblue_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            backGround.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
            textArea.setText("Now we feel blue");
            if (forBLue == true){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Now we feel blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                forBLue = false;
            }
        }
    });

    mygreen_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);
    mygreen_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            backGround.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
            textArea.setText("Now we feel green");
            if (forGreen == true) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now we feel green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                forGreen = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Following is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/textID"
    android:text="Click the button that best represents your mood"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/blue_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BLUE"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/green_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GREEN"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>>
```

Comment: When do you want the toast to be visible again?

Comment: Can you please add your layout too?

Comment: For example: if the user continues to press the blue button, then only show toast in first click and say user presses green button. Then after pressing the green button, he again presses the blue button I want the toast to reappear.

Comment: If you want to enable toasts functionality again after some seconds then use "new Handler()" and its method postDelayed(Runnable, delay); to set the Boolean to true again.

Comment: When user presses green button set the Boolean for blue button to true and green to false, and vice versa

Comment: @Usman is right. And rename your variable for isBlue and isGreen as it's gonna be more explicit. So do something like that: `if (!isBlue){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Now we feel blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isBlue = true;
                    isGreen = false;
                }` for the blue button. (obviously in this scenario, isBlue and isGreen are initialized to `false`)

Comment: Yes, use this logic ^ and I also suggest using setOnClickListener(this) and then using switch(view.getId()) to better manage the click events.

Comment: @Usman You should write and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private int blue, green = 0;

myblue_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                backGround.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
                textArea.setText("Now we feel blue");
                if (blue == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Now we feel blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    blue = 1;
                    green = 0;
                }
            }
        });

        mygreen_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                backGround.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
                textArea.setText("Now we feel green");
                if (green == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now we feel green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    green = 1;
                    blue = 0;
    }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Here is a code this will fix your problem.

Comment: Why have you replaced the booleans by integers? Especially if you're still using 2 variables?

Comment: He is new to coding, will help him get easily, :) Thats why we are here for to help each other

Comment: Thank you. Great logic. I implemented the same logic to my code and it worked beautifully.

Comment: From my point of view it doesn't help. First it's very confusing as you don't know what 0 and 1 means, two you have to write more code as `if (green == 0)` can be replaced by `if(isGreen)` using a boolean, and three it uses more memory

Comment: Brother he already voted for it, this was for him, not for you, I know it very well, look at his code, whats makes you think that it will slow down his android cell phone?

Comment: @Eselfar yes you are correct. I used the boolean technique to do this so that it is less code and saved memory. I liked the logic and I was to implement it on my code easily.

Comment: Good luck then,

Comment: @ZeeshanSardar No but as you said we're here to help each other so it's better to encourage good practices. Especially if you're new with something. :)

Comment: Yes brother, thank you for better approach next time i will keep in mind going for better approach rather than going for easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this :

```
if (forBLue == true){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Now we feel blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                forBLue = false;
                forGreen = true ;//edit here
            }
```

and :

```
if (forGreen == true) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now we feel green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                forGreen = false;
                forBlue = true;//edit here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
boolean shouldShowToastOnBlue = true;
boolean shouldShowToastOnGreen = true;

...

myblue_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        backGround.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
        textArea.setText("Now we feel blue");
        if (shouldShowToastOnBlue){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Now we feel blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            shouldShowToastOnBlue = false;
        }
        shouldShowToastOnGreen = true;
    }
});

mygreen_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);
mygreen_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        backGround.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        textArea.setText("Now we feel green");
        if (shouldShowToastOnGreen) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now we feel green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            shouldShowToastOnGreen = false;
        }
        shouldShowToastOnBlue = true;
    }
});
```